# Center content and make their position adjustable

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to `react` and `css`.
My goal here is to center my 3 switches and the name of them in the center of my page. Then I would like the 3 switches button to adjust their position automatically no matter the length of the text on its left.

Here is what I have for the moment.

This is the `switch button + text`. I made a style to align the text with the middle of the switch icon. I tried the `verticalAlign: "middle"` but it the text went at the bottom position.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Switch from "react-switch";

const SwitchMode = ({text}) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
    const handleChange = StateCheck => {
        setChecked(StateCheck)
    }

    return(
        <div className="switch-position">
            <label>
                <span style={{display: "inline-flex", verticalAlign: '50%', marginRight: '4%'}}>{text}</span>
                <Switch
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={checked}
                className="react-switch"
                />
            </label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SwitchMode
```

And this is the `css` I've made for the moment

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.image-position {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: auto;
}

.service-position {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.switch-position {
  display: inline;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
```

in this file I create my switch button, apply the css and give them a name.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import ReactRoundedImage from "react-rounded-image";
import Img from './images/Diamond.png'
import SwitchMode from './Switch';

const Profile = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className='image-position'>
                <ReactRoundedImage image={Img} roundedSize="0" imageWidth="150" imageHeight="150" />
            </div>
            <div className='service-position'>
            <SwitchMode text="Discord"/>
            <SwitchMode text="Google"/>
            <SwitchMode text="FEJZIOFZEJ"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

this is the actual result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.image-position {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: auto;
}

.service-position {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.switch-position {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

and change your `SwitchMode` component to this:

```
const SwitchMode = ({ text }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (StateCheck) => {
    setChecked(StateCheck);
  };

  return (
    <div className="switch-position">
      <label>
        <span>{text}</span>
        <Switch
          onChange={handleChange}
          checked={checked}
          className="react-switch"
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The main things I did was set `justify-content: center` and `flex-direction: row` on `.service-position`. To make sure the `.switch-position` items displayed in a row and were centered.

For centering the text next to the switch button I used `text-align: center` and to make sure the text is displayed above the switch button I set a fixed with on `.switch-position`.

---

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sun-zu9qb?file=/src/styles.css)